# How to use spacy for extraction of sentences containing specific pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, spacy

I am looking for a good tutorial to use spacy in order to use pattern to extract specific sentences ?. I tried some tuto online but I am looking for a specific one to use  for retrieval sentences.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have any idea. So If I understand you tried to check if the value/word/token which is rfers to as POS/ADJ in your pattern is present in a lexicon ? before retrieve it ? seems a bit difficult for ùme to figure how to help you overcome that. I hope someone in the site will kindly help you, we were all beguinners at first.